# .color JQuery not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jquery which is working fine on firefox and ie but not working in chrome and safari

here it is

```
if (intCurrPortionId == intOldPortionId) {
    $('#' + portionCell + '').css("backgroundColor", "green");
} else {
    $('#' + portionCell + '').css("backgroundColor", "red");
}
```

and this is not working..
m calling this jquery on checkbox onchange event

EDIT: 
It is not executing the function in chrome and safari.. i added the alert in the code and found out that no alerts were popping... now how to tackle it

Comment: why do you have trailing + '' in your selector?

Comment: Can you verify that any styles are being set?

Comment: @BarryChapman m trailing '' coz i will add more var in id once i get this working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#' + portionCell).css("background-color", "green");
```

Comment: didnt worked, I guess i have to go with addclass and removeclass thing nw

Comment: @Sirwani do an `alert(portionCell)` to see if `portionCell` isn't empty or null

Comment: ur suggestion was helpful.. found out that the function is not executing in chrome.. no alerts were popping.. need to sort y is it exhibiting odd behavior..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-color`:

```
if (intCurrPortionId == intOldPortionId) {
    $('#' + portionCell + '').css("background-color", "green");
} else {
    $('#' + portionCell + '').css("background-color", "red");
}
```

FYI, using javascript style parameter names (like `backgroundColor`) works fine for me here in Safari 5.1.2 and Chrome 16:

[Test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FthV3/)